# How do I move the oldest or newest file in a directory to another with Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I'm trying to us the following command on Mac OSX 10.6 Terminal but it does not work..Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

These work...

**List most recent file:**

```
ls -l -t | head -2
```

**List oldest file:**

```
$ ls -gt | tail -1
```

But when I try to **Move the oldest file**, with this it doesn't work:

```
mv `ls -tr |tail -1` newdirname
```

Any ideas or tips are appreciated!! And please be gentle guys, I'm not so good at this command line stuff yet ; )

Thanks,

Jess

Ps.

When I enter this:

```
mv `ls -tr |tail -1` DropBox
```

I get this: `mv: rename Test.txt to DropBox/Test.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: What happens when you fire up the command? Seems to bee good and works on linux.

Comment: Simon, I added the output above.

Comment: Does work on Snow Leopard as well. Any error messages to post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the files you are moving are in the current directory:

```
mv "`ls -1t | tail -1`" dir_to_move_to
```

the quote help for spaces in filename, but I don't think my answer is elegant, any more elegant solution?

Comment: This won't work if the file name contains space. You should change your command line to quote the sub-shell execution result.

Comment: please enlighten us less fortunate  with the modified command

Answer (score 1):

Adding the parameter `-1` to your `ls` will fix that. Seems like osx' ls doesn't check correctly whether it prints to a terminal or a pipe..

Answer (score 0):

You're moving the newest file. Try

```
mv `ls -t |tail -1` newdirname
```

or

```
mv `ls -tr |head -1` newdirname
```

Working on my Ubuntu's bash.

Answer (score 0):

I found the another answer for the problem. The best to use **find** command instead of using **ls** command. It would help to find the oldest file and can use **mv** command to move to another directory.

`mv $(find /home/balaji/work/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1) /home/balaji/regular_archieve`

`find` – Search for files in a directory hierarchy.
`/home/balaji/work/` – Search location.
`/home/balaji/regular_archieve/` – Target location.
`type -f` – Searches only the regular files.
`-printf ‘%T+ %p\n’` – Prints the file’s last modification date and time in separated by + symbol. (Eg. 2015-07-22+13:42:40.0000000000). Here, %p indicates the file name. \n indicates new line.
`sort | head -n 1` – The sort command sorts the output and sends the output to head command to display the oldest file. Here, -n 1 indicates only one file i.e oldest file.